# Money transfer to US - how to make it right?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international-transfer

I've inherited a real estate in another country and I'm going to sell it. All the money from the sale will go to their local bank, and my account at this bank won't be accessible from US.

What should I do to make sure a wire transfer from this foreign bank to any US bank won't lead to any additional charges, like taxes or something else?

Also, are there any upper limits on the transferred amount, which will trigger some additional paperwork etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple wire transfer should be not a problem, and there are no limits on the amount. There are fees for wire transfers, typically in the 30 - 100 USD range, depending on your banks on both ends. Note that there is probably an currency conversion necessary (as your foreign money is probably not in USD), which is the place where some banks bleed you significantly - investigate your options and both bank's fee schedules.

Your tax liabilities are unrelated to the transfer of the money; if you owe taxes on the inheritance, you owe them either way, no matter where the money is, stays, or how it moves. The transfer itself triggers no taxes.